# high xorg processor usage when scrolling or moveing windows after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: xorg, scrolling

after upgrading to the version  13.10 in xubuntu, scrolling and moving windows becomes jagged and slow. When I look at system monitor I see that cpu usage rises for xorg, but only when I scroll, or move a window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with your situation (being an Xfce fan boy myself).

You are probably using Greybird from shimmer project (Xubuntu's default).

It is a wonderful and very lean (written) theme, one of the best available.

Sometimes (I'm not a pro and can't tell why) some themes do not work well for different setups.

Selecting even the xfce themes (xfce-dusk, etc) caused me the same unusable performance you are having (including the Greybird suite which I love). It seems the cause is in the gtk-2.0

---

Solution is to select a different theme (engine) from Settings > Appearance.

---

The ones in the gtk-engines package (Industrial, Redmont, ThinIce, etc) are lag free for me.

CPU load is around 25% while scrolling (on a single core) with the Industrial theme.

Good luck and I hope you have a scroll lag free session.